# simulator doesn't work/unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value/if else code problems

Tags: multithreading, null, simulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mPU.jpg)

**First question**

I want to make going back to "mainViewController" if I click "the button below", but, it doesn't work in "simulator." I don't know how to correct my code.

```
@IBAction func refresh(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeryQ.jpg)

**Second question**

It says

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

if I try to work in simulator. How to solve?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqSGs.jpg)

**Third question**

I want to write code. It will say "right" if you click right button having the sound and It will say "wrong" if you click wrong button having the sound.

How to start?